# How do I style the Woocommerce checkout select option?

Tags: css, woocommerce, jquery-select2

I'm trying to change the style of the select (dropdown) field in my Woocommerce checkout page. I'm using it with the DIVI theme.

by default the select field does not have the same height as the other:

[image]

I managed to find the part to do that in the css by playing with the padding on this class:

```
.woocommerce-input-wrapper .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single
```

but then the select option and the arrow are not in the middle:

[image]

I can move the content of the field if I decrease the line-height here:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered
```

but if I decrease it too much, the text will be cut off

[image]

How can I move the content of the field to the middle properly?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a url for this page ?

Comment: You can check it here: https://rhinoacademy.net/checkout/?add-to-cart=216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Change the 40px in the below code to your desired value. Tested and working in windows, google chrome.

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single{
    height: 40px !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{
    height: 40px !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{
    line-height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)